# Read the text from PDF with itextsharp without formatting changed

Tags: c#, pdf, formatting, itext

Hi I have been trying to read the content of a PDF file using itextsharp into a string in C#.net with the formatting as it is in the file.

My input is a PDF file having the contents like

```
 hi, how are you?         I hope you are fine.
        how is everything            else?
```

And i want to read the content as it is with the same formatting(I don't want it to read more than certain number of spaces as newline)...

But i am getting it as

```
 hi, how are you?         
 I hope you are fine.
 how is everything            
 else?
```

For this i am using simple code as

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("c:\\Sample.pdf");    
string pdftext = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1,new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());
            Console.WriteLine(pdftext);
```

Could you please help me with it.

Comment: There is no such thing as tabs or multiple spaces in a PDF file. Text is added at absolute positions using coordinates. This means that you'll have to write more code (probably available at the same place where you got the `GetTextFromPage()` snippet and use the coordinates returned by the `TextRenderInfo` object.

Comment: Can encoding be helpful?

Comment: What do you mean by encoding? Stuff like Unicode, Latin-1,...? Why would that be relevant? You're making some strange assumptions. For instance: suppose that you have regular text and bold text. This would mean that you'll have to examine the font that is used because the text will be drawn using two different fonts. Suppose that some text is colored. This means that you'll have to parse text state operators to keep track of the fill color. You're asking something that isn't trivial. It's not a question somebody can answer in a handful code samples.